# ASP.NET MVC Setting RadioButtonFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

MVC 4:

I have the following radio controls

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(o => o.TradeOrder.Exchange, "CA", new {id = "exchangeCA"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(o => o.TradeOrder.Exchange, "US", new {id = "exchangeUS"})
```

**o.TradeOrder.Exchange** is a string, but doesn't contain "CA" or "US" nessesarily, so we override is as shown.

How would I set the CA radio control checked if **o.TradeOrder.Exchange=="X"** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(o => o.TradeOrder.Exchange, "US", new {id = "exchangeUS"},new { Checked = (o.TradeOrder.Exchange=="X" ? "Checked" : string.Empty) )
```